# Duplicates between Mysql and hdfs with flume?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, flume

Is there any duplicacy occurring when we use Flume to get live streaming data from mysql database?
And how does flume store the live data on table created on hdfs?

Comment: Are you aware of the mysql transaction log? Have you observed duplicates? Why did you tag sqoop?

Comment: Yes i am aware of logs. But In case if i got any duplicates then what.

Comment: My point is that it's not Flume's responsibility to remove duplicates and if you're trying to use it like so, then it personally think you're using the wrong tool. If you want to stream data, you use Debezium to turn a table into a stream of *transactional updates* (meaning all events are unique based on time),  and Flume has no JDBC source out of the box, so I would suggest using Kafka JDBC Connect instead, (assuming you had Kafka). And Kafka Connect also writes to HDFS... **Or** Hadoop is not a steaming tool, and treating it as one is wrong, so live with hourly Sqoop tasks

Comment: okkk.....thanks.....

Comment: I'm just confused why/how you planned on using Flume for this when I personally have not seen this use case in the Flume documentation

Comment: Flume is used for getting streaming sets of data from database to hdfs. Then I thought if there is any duplicates entries will come in the database then can flume is able to remove any type of redundancy happens in the table.  May be I have got any misconception about flume.

Comment: Where are you reading that Flume consumes any database events? How do you define duplicates? If you have a primary key on a table, all rows must be unique

Comment: Yss I got it......Sir actually I have got a project so can u help me out...i am not able to chat in this .... so is there any other platform where you can help me??

Comment: I'm not available here to give project guidance, and I'm biased in my toolsets. But if you're streaming anything, Kafka is becoming like an industry standard. Then if you want to plug a database into it http://debezium.io/blog/#about_debezium

Comment: okk no problem... thanxx.....

Answer (score 0):

Look at the log images [in this post](https://community.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11114.streaming-mysql-database-table-data-to-hdfs-with-flume)

You see that when the Flume action sees a new table entry, the `id > X` is constantly increasing the value of X.

Flume (should) internally maintain the previous consumed ID values on the filesystem of the agent